# How to hide a tooltip when scrolling?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am using an Angular directive allowing me to display a tooltip with the mouseEnter and mouseLeave events.

everything works fine except that when I scroll the tooltip does not disappear and remains displayed.

[image]

I tried using the @Hostlistener listener but it doesn't work on mobile.

> ```
> @HostListener('document:wheel', ['$event.target'])   public onWheel()
> {
> if (this.tooltip) {
>   this.renderer.removeClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip-show');
>  }   
> }
> ```

Do you have a solution ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-directive-uprxbd?file=app%2Ftooltip.directive.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
<div class="tooltip-example" style="margin-top:100px">
   <div [tooltip]="displayStatut()" placement="top" delay="500">tootip on top</div>
 </div>
 `,
 styles: [`
.tooltip-example {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 50px;
 }
.tooltip-example [tooltip] {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.ng-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background: #282a36;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ng-tooltip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
}
.ng-tooltip-top:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.ng-tooltip-bottom:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}
.ng-tooltip-left:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent black;
}
.ng-tooltip-right:after {
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.ng-tooltip-show {
  opacity: 1;
  }
 `]
 })

 export class AppComponent {

public displayStatut() {
let content;
content += "<ul style='margin-bottom:10px;text-align: left'><li>Test</li></ul>";
return content;
  }
}
```

**tooltip.directive.ts**

> ```
> import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 }
> from '@angular/core';
>
> @Directive({   selector: '[tooltip]' }) export class TooltipDirective
> {   @Input('tooltip') tooltipTitle: string;   @Input() placement:
> string;   @Input() delay: string;   tooltip: HTMLElement;   
> tooltip 
> offset = 10;
>
> constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }
>
> @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
> if (!this.tooltip) { this.show(); }   }
>
> @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
> if (this.tooltip) { this.hide(); }   }
>
> show() {
> this.create();
> this.setPosition();
> this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip-show');   }
>
> hide() {
> this.renderer.removeClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip-show');
> window.setTimeout(() => {
>   this.renderer.removeChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
>   this.tooltip = null;
> }, this.delay);   }
>
> create() {
> this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('span');
>
> this.renderer.appendChild(
>   this.tooltip,
>   this.renderer.createText(this.tooltipTitle) // textNode
> );
>
> this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
> // this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.tooltip);
>
> this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip');
> this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, `ng-tooltip-${this.placement}`);
>
> // delay
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, '-webkit-transition', `opacity 
> ${this.delay}ms`);
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, '-moz-transition', `opacity ${this.delay}ms`);
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, '-o-transition', `opacity ${this.delay}ms`);
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, 'transition', `opacity ${this.delay}ms`);   }
>
>  setPosition() {
> const hostPos = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
>
> // tooltip
> const tooltipPos = this.tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
>
> // window scroll top
> // getBoundingClientRect 
> viewport.
> const scrollPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || 
>  document.body.scrollTop || 0;
>
> let top, left;
>
> if (this.placement === 'top') {
>   top = hostPos.top - tooltipPos.height - this.offset;
>   left = hostPos.left + (hostPos.width - tooltipPos.width) / 2;
> }
>
> if (this.placement === 'bottom') {
>   top = hostPos.bottom + this.offset;
>   left = hostPos.left + (hostPos.width - tooltipPos.width) / 2;
> }
>
> if (this.placement === 'left') {
>   top = hostPos.top + (hostPos.height - tooltipPos.height) / 2;
>   left = hostPos.left - tooltipPos.width - this.offset;
> }
>
> if (this.placement === 'right') {
>   top = hostPos.top + (hostPos.height - tooltipPos.height) / 2;
>   left = hostPos.right + this.offset;
> }
>  
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, 'top', `${top + scrollPos}px`);
> this.renderer.setStyle(this.tooltip, 'left', `${left}px`);   } }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried with CSS ?
For example

```
.ng-tooltip {
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
}
```